# DVD's won't play with 13.10

Tags: dvd

DVD's used to play with 12.04, but since I upgraded to 13.10 I can't get any type of dvd to read. I have tried Totem and VLC. I have also installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321
```

and

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to install the [restricted formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), should be as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: The restricted extras have already been installed. I have rebooted a couple of times and now it will read some commercial dvd's in VLC. DVD+R or DVD-R can't be read. Totem can't read anything.